# Is the absolute version of FloatBuffer.put thread-safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, floatbuffer

There are multiple `put` methods for java.nio.FloatBuffer. As far as I know, most (all?) of them depend on an internal state of the buffer, so they are not thread-safe. My question is if this also applies for the following method?

```
public abstract FloatBuffer put(int index, float f)
```

[The documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html#put(int,%20float)):

> Absolute put method  (optional operation).
>
> Writes the given float into this buffer at the given index.

In my case at hand it would be no problem if an update is lost/overwritten from time to time, but it would be fatal if a write happened on a completely different index (because the internal position is overwritten before the value is put or something like that).

Comment: The method is `abstract`, it depends on the implementation

Comment: [`Buffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html) says: *"Buffers are not safe for use by multiple concurrent threads. If a buffer is to be used by more than one thread then access to the buffer should be controlled by appropriate synchronization."* There are at least visibility problems if one thread writes to an absolute position and another one reads the data.

Comment: A `FloatBuffer` might be a [view into a `ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asFloatBuffer()) so there is not even a guaranty that this modification is atomic. It might consist of four byte updates.